# Solution to $\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+y=\sec\left(t\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a solution to the following differential equation?
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+y=\sec\left(t\right)
\end{equation}

---

Answer (score 1):

The function $y(t) =t \sin(t)+\cos(t) \log(\cos(t))$ is a solution (for example). (See Taylor Martin's answer on where this is a valid solution).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Picard existence theory, of course this ODE has solutions.  But it should be evident, since $|\sec t|\to\infty$ as $|t|\to\pi/2+n\pi$, that such solutions only exist on finite intervals and no solution exists for all $t$.  Finding an explicit solution is straight forward enough using standard ODE solution techniques for linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by variation of parameter method,

$\textbf{Hint}$: First find solution of homogeneous equation 
$(D^2+1)y=0$

The auxiliary equation is,

$D^2+1=0$ implies $D=\pm i$

therefore,the solution of above homogeneous equation,

$$y_h=c_1 \cos t+c_2 \sin t$$

Now,for particular solution of give equation use this formula to find non-homogeneous differential equation,

$$y_p=-y_1(t)\int \frac{y_2(t)r(t)}{W}+y_2(t) \int \frac{y_1(t)r(t)}{W}$$

where $W(y_1,y_2)=\left| \begin{array}{cc}
y_1 & y_2  \\
y_1' & y_2'  \end{array} \right|$ and $r(t)= \sec t$(in this case).

Answer (score 0):

$$(D^2+1)y=\sec x$$

Its auxiliary equation is $D^2+1=0 \implies D=\pm \, i$

Thus its complimentary function is
$$CF=c_1 \cos x+c_2 \sin x$$

Calculating the PI
$$PI={1 \over D^2+1^2} \sec x={1 \over (D-i)(D+i)}\sec x={1 \over 2i} ({1 \over D-i}-{1 \over D+i})$$

Now

$${1 \over D-i}\sec x=e^{ix} \int \sec x \, e^{-ix} \, dx=e^{ix}(x+i \ln \cos x)$$

Similarly,

$${1 \over D+i}\sec x=e^{-ix} \int \sec x \, e^{ix} \, dx=e^{-ix}(x-i \ln \cos x)$$

Thus PI=$${e^{ix}(x+i \ln \cos x)-e^{-ix}(x-i \ln \cos x) \over 2i}$$

On a little simplification the PI transforms to

$$x \sin x +\cos x \ln \cos x$$

Therefore, the complete solution is
$$y=c_1 \cos x+c_2 \sin x+ x \sin x +\cos x \ln \cos x$$

$\mathbf {Note:}$
See Taylor Martin's answer.